# What is the most standard pallet structure in Substrate?

Tags: pallet, error, configuration, config, struct

I wonder if there is a structure in pallets, which other projects should follow.

We have the following elements:

1. < Config trait >
2. < Types >
3. < Storage >
4. < Genesis info>
5. < Events >
6. < Error >
7. < Hooks>
8. < Dispatchables >
9. < Pallet public and private functions >
10. < Trait Implementations >

Are there any elements missing? If yes, make a suggestion of your structure with the new elements inside!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aside from the outer

```
#[pallet]
mod pallet {}
```

and the fact that everything needs to be inside of this, internals of a pallet are almost entirely normal Rust and the mentioned items can appear anywhere with any order.

Here are some suggested best-practices:

- Config trait should come first.
- Place all storage items next to each other.
- I would put the types at the top.